# ASP.NET Core 1.1 fails to run when published

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

I had an ASP.NET Core application that I just went in an upgraded to 1.1.  This application worked fine previously and I could publish it (through Publish Command in Visual Studio) and it worked fine under IIS.  I recent changed this be 1.1 and got the application to run in debug mode fine.  Now when I publish it I get

```
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
```

I turned on Failed Request Tracing Rules and in there I see the following

```
MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 

ModuleName httpPlatformHandler 
Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 
HttpStatus 502 
HttpReason Bad Gateway 
HttpSubStatus 3 
ErrorCode The server is currently disabled. (0x8007053d)
```

My published web.config file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="httpPlatform" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Cranalytics.dll" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My project.json file looks like this

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",

    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",

    "Syncfusion.Compression.MVC": "14.2600.0.32-preview2-final",
    "Syncfusion.XlsIO.MVC": "14.2600.0.32-preview2-final",

    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.2",

    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",

    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },

    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
    //"net461": {
    //  "dependencies": {
    //  },
    //  "imports": "dnxcore50"
    //}
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config",
      "appsettings.Production.json",
      "appsettings.Staging.json",
      "appsettings.json"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

I can't find out what the problem is with the configuration or IIS.

Edit:
I made some changes to configuration and am now past the module loading section (at least according to the Trace Log).  Now I'm just getting 404 whenever I visit the website.  I can view static images without a problem, but when I view the home page to the site I get a 404 error

```
ModuleName AspNetCoreModule 
Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 
HttpStatus 404 
HttpReason Not Found 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode The operation completed successfully. (0x0)
```

My published directory structure is a sub site underneath the root site in IIS (/Cranalytics).  Then in that folder is all of the various DLL, along with the web.config.  Under this directory is the wwwroot directory from the project.  The IIS subsite is set pointing to the root site (/Cranalytics).

Comment: Why old IIS package? Current version is http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools/1.1.0-preview4-final

Comment: Have you also installed the 1.1.0 runtime?

Comment: tseng I changed it to 1.1.0-preview4-final
   
Martin I have installed DotNetCore.1.1.0-WindowsHosting on the server

Comment: Are your project framework is the same with framework in application pool?

Comment: Project Framework is ASP.NET Core 1.1 and AppPool has No Managed Code as the Framework version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this site was being update from RC1 to 1.1.  To get RC1 to work there were several things that I needed to undo.  In IIS when I created the site I had change the path from the root of the subsite Cranalytics to the wwwroot underneath that.  This had to be undone.

Then in the Configure I needed to have something like this because it was a subsite.  This had to be removed as well.

```
        //if (env.IsDevelopment())
        //{
        //    Configure1(app, env, loggerFactory, context);
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    app.Map("/Cranalytics", app1 => Configure1(app1, env, loggerFactory, context));
        //}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some Idea to Help.

```
1.Check Directory Browsing of your website if it is in enable state or not.
2.Try to separate your project to a new website with different port.
-also configure the newly created web site of course.
3.framework in application pool vs project, it must be the same.
```

Comment: The AppPool's .NET CLR Version is set to No Managed Code.  Directory Browsing is enabled.  I can't create a separate website.  Because it is on a server that is already established.  There are other subsites on this same server that are 1.0 and even some that are RC of ASP.NET.

Comment: I created another test website is IIS using port 88 just to test this out and then made a copy of the site into a subsite under the new port 88 site and I got the same error when I viewed the new site by IP:88.  I tried removing the httpPlatformHandler from the list of modules on the new site, but then I get a different error saying   "Handler "httpPlatformHandler" has a bad module "httpPlatformHandler" in its module list"